# Passing data from nodeJs to c# wpf

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, websocket

My web project was build using php & nodeJs for passing data from server to client, everything work properly. till one day i must to add some feature in my project that have a **direct print from server to client (desktop app)** capability. let me show you my nodeJs code

```
const http = require('http')
const socket = require('socket.io')

const server = http.createServer()
const io = socket.listen(server)
const port = 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server listen at', port)
})

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('print_this_stuff', function(data) {
        io.emit('print'+data['id'],data) //hope will send notif to desktop client
    })
})
```

**my planning workflow**

1. web user clicking button on his page and will trigger action in nodeJs
2. nodeJs will emit his function to send notification to client (c#)
3. c# receive notification
4. and finally c# will be printing

**Question**

how my client receive notification from server ? maybe someone write the code for this or maybe someone have a better solution to achieve my problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got solution for this. maybe anyone out there have a project like this.

follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUZV8oK_1nA it works.